# How to use union query in criteria->condiion in Yii?

Tags: php, mysql, yii

```
SELECT p_name
FROM projects
WHERE m_id =3
UNION SELECT p.p_name
FROM projects p, tasks t, users u
WHERE t.t_assignee =3
AND p.m_id =3
AND u.role !=1
```

This is my query, and I want to implement this query in my model. I have used 3 tables in this query. Here comes my model projects. Here I want the list according to above query.

```
public function search()
{
    // Warning: Please modify the following code to remove attributes that
    // should not be searched.

    $criteria=new CDbCriteria;

    $criteria->compare('project_id',$this->project_id);
    $criteria->compare('p_name',$this->project_name,true);
    $criteria->compare('m_id',$this->manager_id);
    $criteria->compare('description',$this->description,true);


        return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
        'criteria'=>$criteria,
    ));



}
```

How can I implement this query here?

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
'id'=>'projects-grid',
'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
'ajaxUpdate' => false,
'filter'=>$model,
'columns'=>array(
array(
'name' => 'project_id',
'value'=>'$data["project_id"]', //in the case we want something custom
  ),
array(
'name' => 'project_name',
'value'=>'$data["project_name"]', //in the case we want something custom
),
array(
'name' => 'manager_id',
'value'=>'$data["manager_id"]', //in the case we want something custom
                    ),
array(
'name'=>'description',
'value'=>'strip_tags($data["description"])'
),  
array(
'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
'template'=>'{view} {update} {delete}{createtask}{viewtask}',
'buttons'=>array
(

),
),
),
));
```

This is my cgridview view. Trying to get property of non-object still shows.

Answer (score 0):

In this case using [CSqlDataProvider](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CSqlDataProvider) will be much easier than CActiveDataProvider:

```
$sql = "
SELECT p_name
FROM projects
WHERE m_id =3
UNION SELECT p.p_name
FROM projects p, tasks t, users u
WHERE t.t_assignee = :t_assignee
AND p.m_id = :m_id
AND u.role != :role
";

return new CSqlDataProvider($sql, [
    'params' => [
        ':t_assignee' => 3,
        ':m_id' => $this->manager_id,
        ':role' => 1,
    ]
]);
```

And you have to add additional properties to the 'projects' model to be able to search by 'role' and 't_assignee' fields

Comment: Thanks for your reply.still having issue on line 'params' => [ . 
  * here comes this double arrow error

Comment: '[]' is short [syntax for arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#example-96)(it was added in PHP 5.4), replace it with 'array()' - maybe you have lower version

Comment: still having double arrow error.here is my code.$sql = "
SELECT project_name
FROM projects
WHERE manager_id ='".Yii::app()->user->getid()."'
UNION SELECT p.project_name
FROM projects p, tasks t, users u
WHERE t.task_assignee = :task_assignee
AND p.manager_id = :manager_id
AND u.role != :role
";

return new CSqlDataProvider($sql, 
    'params'=>'array(
        ':task_assignee' => 3,
        ':manager_id' =>3,
        ':role' => 1
    )'
);

Comment: it is because of quote before array. replace it with: $sql = " SELECT project_name FROM projects WHERE manager_id ='".Yii::app()->user->getid()."' UNION SELECT p.project_name FROM projects p, tasks t, users u WHERE t.task_assignee = :task_assignee AND p.manager_id = :manager_id AND u.role != :role "; return new CSqlDataProvider($sql, array('params'=>array( ':task_assignee' => 3, ':manager_id' =>3, ':role' => 1 )));

Comment: It shows Trying to get property of non-object ..should i have to do anything on project controller or on admin(view page) as it is a result of join query of 3 tables projects,tasks and users.
 iam listing projects according to this query in admin view of projects.

Comment: Ok. Provide code where you invoke search() method. Do you invoke it manually in controller or it invokes automatically by grid widget? And also please show edited search() method

Comment: yet to solve the issue.was busy with other works.help me to solve the issue

Comment: Now in sql query you select only "p_name". But as I see, you need "p_name as project_name, project_id, m_id as manager_id, description". Try analyzing error messages and stack trace, usually they say where mistake is.